# Is a static char[] buffer initialised

Tags: c++

I have this at file scope:

`static char foo[256];`

Is the memory initialised to zero on all platforms and build configurations? (i.e. is it standard C++).

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed by the C++ standard. If you find out that the contents of the array are not zeroed, you have a nonconforming compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the memory initialised to zero on all platforms and build configurations?

Yes, all non-local variables are zero-initialised.

> (i.e. is it C++ standard)

Yes. C++11 3.6.2 specifies how non-local variables are initialised. In particular:

> 2. Variables with **static storage duration** or thread storage duration shall be **zero-initialized** before any other initialization takes place.